# Dump the letters of the alphabet to a series of Pngs from the command line?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I'd like to create a bunch of PNGs, one for each letter of the alphabet.

How can I do this from the command line on mac/linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an image of the letter using **Inkscape** and setting whatever style and color you want.
Let's say you create one with the letter A and save it as `a.svg`
Then locate where the `A` is, for example

```
style="font-size:72px;fill:#8b0000">A</tspan></text>
```

and replace it in a loop

```
for l in {A..Z}; do sed 's@\(#8b0000">\)\(A\)\(</tspan></text>\)@\1'$l'\3@' a.svg | convert - $l.png; done
```

and you'll have all your letters

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I really like the SVG idea!

Answer (score 1):

The following script will dump the letters of the alphabet to a series of PNGs. It requires imageMagick and GhostScript be installed on your system for the `convert` utility.

e.g.

```
# creates the letters A.png -> Z.png in the current folder
dump_alphabet_as_pngs.sh   

# creates the files test_A.png -> test_Z.png in the current folder, 
# with a red font named "AvantGarde-Book"
dump_alphabet_as_pngs.sh test_ red AvantGarde-Book
```

#### dump_alphabet_as_pngs.sh

```
# Create image for template
TEMPLATE=/tmp/_template.png
convert -size 80x80 xc:white $TEMPLATE

# Setup defaults
PREFIX=${1:-''}
COLOR=${2:-'red'}
FONT=${3:-'helvetica'}
SIZE=${4:-75}

# Note that the following will show you fonts you can use: 'convert -list font |grep Font:'

function createImage()
{
  convert -font $FONT -fill $COLOR -pointsize $SIZE -draw "text 15,70 '$1'" $TEMPLATE $PREFIX$1.png
}

# Generate images
for x in {A..Z}
do
  createImage $x
done

rm -f $TEMPLATE
```

[image]